# Liferay 6.0.12 logging

Tags: logging, liferay, jboss5.x, liferay-6

I've ecnountered some problems with logging Liferay 6.0.12 classes on JBoss 5.1.

I need to change log-level for Liferay rss portlet classes, e.g. create another appender or use the default one (server.log) and have logs there with desired debug-level (`DEBUG` or `WARN`).

As far as i understand `jboss-log4j.xml` may override Liferay's configuration, so i tried to modify it. Also I've tried do this from `log4j.properties` in `ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes`, tried creating `portal-log4j-ext.xml` but none of them worked for me. The only thing i could do - to create another appender, but it was either empty or copy server.log.

Does anybody knows how exactly does it work?

PS Managing log-levels through admin portlet is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately i solved this problem.

1. First of all, add log4j.jar to `ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib`, somehow it's not there.
2. The second check if there are any `log4j.xml` in classpath(just search
   for any in `ROOT.war`)
3. If there is any you're able to create `log4.xml` `in ROOT.war/WEB-INF/classes` with desired appender and log-levels.
4. If there is no any you may use either log4j.xml or `log4j.properties` (for desired appender) and `portal-log4j-ext.xml` (to override default log-levels) due to Liferay documentation.